# Field 'created_date' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String username;

@Size(max = 50)
@Email
private String email;

@CreationTimestamp
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Date createdDate;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String address;
private String phone;

@Size(max = 120)
private String password;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private AuthProvider provider;

private String providerId;

private boolean enabled;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

public User() {
}

public User(

    String email, String password) {
    this.email = email;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.address = address;
    this.password = password;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.provider = provider;
    this.createdDate = new Date();
     
}

//GETTER AND SETTER
```

**data.sql**

```
INSERT INTO users(email,enabled,password,username,provider) VALUES('abc@gmail.com',1,'$2a$10$ideoxDhZo1MP9eW.A4UC0.4iPeDeCNM9yVMGQFpzTz04OZp9nxw5S','username','local');
```

**error**

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'created_date' doesn't have a default value
```

I was trying to add a created_date field but get error while inserting sql through data.sql. However, I got the error 'Field 'created_date' doesn't have a default value'
How to let jpa/hibernate to insert the date automatically, just like the @GeneratedValue for ID ? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using JPA to insert or native sql query ?

Comment: I use hibernate to create the table and insert data by native sql query in data.sql file

Comment: if you are trying the native query as posted in question, the column should have a default value(table definition) so that it will be updated on insert

Comment: ALTER TABLE users MODIFY created_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE);
something like this needs to be done for the native query execution to work

Comment: correct , but hibernate was smart and could auto generate the 'id' field, so I thought I could do something similar with 'created_date'

Comment: pls can you check, for id is auto increment enabled in table

Comment: if 'id' has @GeneratedValue, then is there same kind of annotation for 'date' ? that was what I was looking for.

Comment: columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" something like this needs to be added along with other params of @column. This will be applied at table level by ORM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this will work for you in this case.

```java
@CreationTimestamp
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
private Date createdDate;
```